# Badge notifications

Tags: bug, badges, notifications

Sometimes I get an notification of a new badge, sometimes I don't.. Is this a bug or are some badges not special enough to get a notification of?

[image: My latest notifications]

As you can see I got a notification of the [php](/questions/tagged/php) badge, but just before that I also earned the `cleanup` badge, I noticed a new badge on my profile and found out I never saw that one before. So, why have some badges notification and others none?